# How to render Radio into antd Table

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, antd

I'm trying to render Radio button into a column of antd table without any success.

There's a way to do it?

I tried also use regular HTML input tag with the type of radio without any success.

Option 1:

```
render: (isService) => (
   <span>
      <input type="radio" checked={isService} />
   </span>
)
```

Option 2:

```
render: (isService) => (
   <span>
      <Radio value={isService}></Radio>
   </span>
)
```

**The expected result** will be a table that one of its columns will contain a Radio (one of my fields of the object is boolean so this is the way I want to show it).

Comment: Show your columns object and data, try adding a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-antd-react-starter-lt4l5

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `ReactNode` from [`render` property of `Column`](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column).

With your example, it seems you have a problem with the `columns` / `dataSource` properties provided to your `Table`.

A simple working example:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street'
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street'
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name'
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
    render: age => <Radio checked={age >= 40} />
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address'
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57805758-RenderRadioButton]

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons operate as a group and are used when there is a list of two or more options that are mutually exclusive and a user must select exactly one choice. The radio group must have the same name (the value of the "name" attribute). Selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any other selected radio button in the same group:

```html
<p>Please select your gender:</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
```

Probably in your case you need a checkbox element. A single stand-alone checkbox element is used for a single binary option such as a yes-or-no question:

```html
<label>
  Service
  <input name="service" type="checkbox" checked={isService} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers!

My problem was I had a search box for each column and when I removed it from the column of the Radio button, it appeared! Maybe the search option of the Antd is problematic with adding Radio/Button and something other than simple text or a link.